# Classes in an Android package

Tags: android, class, package, adb

Is there any easy method by which I could list down all classes in an android package? I'm trying to launch an application from ADB shell using:

```
am start -n <package-name>/.<class-name>
```

To list down all android packages, I'm using:

```
pm list package -l
```

I'm very new to adb, so please bear with me if the question seems silly! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ctrl+(space) listout all classes in a package

Comment: By which way you want to list out classes of packege ?
Programmatically or via shell commands ?

Answer (score -3):

Try - CTL + O it list all methods in a class.Hope it works for you.

Comment: I've an apk file installed in my phone. Can you please elaborate? I know how to list down all apps installed on my phone along with their classes. Could you please elaborate more? I guess you're providing keyboard shortcut of an IDE..

Comment: @VinitShandilya You question is misguiding that is why other giving shortcut of IDE. Better you modify  your question.